# Attaching a directive dynamically to a child of current directive upon event

Tags: angularjs

My directive "addOnce" is required to check if it has an "restrict" attribute and if yes, then attach certain other directives to the input box which is one of it's sub-children.

I have been able to layout a framework to get this done. However getting stuck at how I can dynamically attach other directives to the input box.

Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jYiTtTQ0uPuH40zcMcer

```
app.directive('addOnce', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {

    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){

      if(attrs.restrict){
        var input = el.find('input');

        $timeout(function(){
          input.val('testing');  
        }, 50)


        // now attach directive restrict-symbols to the input box
        // as a result the html would look like
         //<input type="text" class="aClass" ng-model="aModel" restrict-symbols>
      }


    }
  };

}]);
```

Any clues will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessary part for nested directives would be:

```
input.attr('restrict-symbols', '');
$compiled = $compile(input)(scope);
```

Take a look at the modified plunkr for the full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/HCTGj1ivp48cUXBXpn1Q?p=preview

What I did was simply to add the needed attribute to the input field, afterwards compile the element, so the nested directive gets executed. The code of the second directive is not very sophisticated but enough to demonstrate that it works